# русский язык и mysql

Tags: mysql

Наверное, я буду уже миллиардным человеком, который спросит как сделать так, чтобы  mysql начал понимать русский язык. Я перепробовал все доступные мне инструменты, прописывал в таблице UTF, CP1251, как в колонках, так и в свойствах самой таблицы, пробовал писать при коннекте к базе вот так

```
jdbc:mysql://eu-cdbr-west-02.cleardb.net:3306/heroku_ab7637be43866cf?charset=utf8
```

делал сет чарсет перед каждым вводом .....

```
import java.sql.Driver;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        Driver driver;
        driver=new com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver();
        DriverManager.registerDriver(driver);


//        ApiContextInitializer.init();
//        TelegramBotsApi telegramBotsApi = new TelegramBotsApi();
//        Botstart1 bot = new Botstart1();
//        try {
//            telegramBotsApi.registerBot(bot);
//        } catch (TelegramApiRequestException e) {
//            e.printStackTrace();
//        }
         Bdate ss=new Bdate();
        try {
           // ss.bd("set names utf8");
            ss.bd("update  users set username = 'уаыаыы' where userId=535077417");
            ss.bs("select username from users where userid=535077417");
            System.out.println(  ss.res.getString(1));
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
```

}
    }

```
public class Bdate{
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://eu-cdbr-west-02.cleardb.net:3306/heroku_ab7637be43866cf?charset=utf8";
    String name="*******";
    String password="*******";
    Connection con;

    {
        try {
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,name,password);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    ResultSet res;


    public void bd(String sql) throws SQLException {





        con.createStatement().execute(sql);







    }
    public  void bs(String sql)throws SQLException{



        res=con.createStatement().executeQuery(sql);
        res.next();
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А вы выставили collation: utf8_unicode_ci для таблиц и колонок?

Comment: Опишите чётко, с кодом без нытья, что и как вы сделали, как помещаете данные и как читаете их, иначе нам ничего не останется, кроме как посоветовать всё то же самое

Comment: выставлял конечно и для таблиц и для колонок Ut8

Comment: то есть хотите сказать, что пишите кириллицей в таблице прямо в workbench и он не принимает? или в чем дело?

Comment: когда пишешь в воркбенч он записывает кирилицу коректно и выводит тоже,но если я посылаю запрос на запись -вместо кирилицы будут ?????

Comment: Проблема как оказалось лежит в JDBC,перед созданием подлючения к базе нужно в url добавить вот такой кусок текста  ?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8